# how can i escape data from text box in django

Tags: python, django

I have the simple form in django which i am submitting via GET.

Now i entered this data in textbox `dsadsadsadsadsa4325435;';',,,.,##$^*(((&(`

In my function i have this line

`re.search(data, alltext)`

now i am getting error `nothing to repeat` in there.

How can i `filter / escape` the data so that my that function works without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.escape(your_string)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape any characters that have a special meaning in regex.